# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran (matlab)

Tags: 14.04, matlab, fortran

I try to use `mex` some toolbox using matlab. But I got these errors: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran`

I used Ubuntu 14.04. I installed `gfortran`. Could any one help ?

this is the output of : `ldconfig -p | grep fortran`

```
xiaoma@laptop:~$ ldconfig -p | grep fortran
    libhdf5hl_fortran.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5hl_fortran.so.7
    libhdf5_fortran.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_fortran.so.7
    libgfortran.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3
```

Comment: I faced same error and eventually `~$ sudo apt-get install libgfortran-*` to install all versions to cope with it. these `sudo apt-get install r-cran-mex` very useful which can let us install through terminal :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible solution:

1. Link `libgfortran.so.3` to `libgfortran.so`

   ```
   ln -s libgfortran.so.3 libgfortran.so
   ```
2. Rebuild ld cache

   ```
   sudo ldconfig
   ```
3. Reinstall the lib

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary for more info.